# Possible causes of performance difference between two very similar Spark Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on improving the performance of some Spark operations for a recommendation engine I am prototyping. I have stumbled upon a significant performance differences between to DataFrames I am using. Below the results of describe() on both.

df1 (fast, numPartitions = 4):

```
+-------+------------------+--------------------+
|summary|           item_id|          popularity|
+-------+------------------+--------------------+
|  count|            187824|              187824|
|   mean| 96693.34836868558|                 1.0|
| stddev|55558.023793621316|5.281958866780519...|
|    min|                 0|  0.9999999999999998|
|    max|            192806|                 1.0|
+-------+------------------+--------------------+
```

df2 (approx. 10x slower, numPartitions = ±170):

```
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
|summary|          item_id|            count|
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  count|           187824|           187824|
|   mean|96693.34836868558|28.70869537439305|
| stddev|55558.02379362146|21.21976457710462|
|    min|                0|                1|
|    max|           192806|              482|
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Both DataFrames are cached, the same size in terms of rows (187824) and columns (2), and have an identical `item_id` column. The main difference is that frame 1 contains float in the second column, whereas frame 2 contains integer.

It seems as if every operation for DataFrame 2 is much slower, ranging from simply the `.describe().show()` operation, to more elaborate `.subtract().subtract().take()`. In the latter case DataFrame 2 takes 18 seconds, as opposed to 2 seconds for frame 1 (almost 10 times slower!).

I don't know where to begin to look for an explanation of the cause of this difference. Any tips or nudges in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: as proposed by Viacheslav Rodionov the number of partitions of the dataframes seems to be the cause of the performance issues with df2.

Digging deeper, both dataframes are a result of `.groupBy().agg().sortBy()` operations on the same original dataframe. The `.groupBy().agg()` operation yields 200 partitions, and then `.sortBy()` returns respectively 4 and ±170 partitions, why could this be?

Comment: I'll start with looking at df.rdd.getNumPartitions()

Comment: The number of partitions is 174 (slow) vs. 4 (fast). Thanks for this tip, I remember reading something about this, I will dig deeper to understand the situation.

The number of partitions was chosen automatically by Spark. Is trial, error and adjusting manually the only way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start with looking at `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`

Smaller number of bigger partitions is almost always a good idea as it allows data to be compressed better and to do more actual work rather then manipulating files.

The other thing to look at is how your data looks like. Is it appropriate to a task you're trying to do?

- If it's ordered by date field which you're using to apply a `BETWEEN` operation it will be faster than just working with unsorted data.
- If you work with specific months or years it will make sense to partition your data by them.
- The same goes for IDs. If you work with certain IDs, put same ID 'closer' to each other by partitioning/sorting your dataset.

My rule of thumb when storing the data - first partition by few low-cardinality fields (booleans and dates mostly), then sort **all** other fields with `sortWithinPartitions` in data importance order. This way you will achieve the best compression rate (means faster processing time) and a better data locality (again faster processing time). But as always it all depends on your use case, always think how you work with your data and prepare it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually both Dataframes are sorted by their second columns (count and popularity respectively). Also, both frames are the result of `.groupBy().agg().sortBy()` operations from the same original Dataframe. It looks like the step `groupBy.agg()` yields 200 partitions in both cases, whereas `sortBy` yields 4 and ~170 respectively. Now trying to distill why this is happening

Comment: I can confirm that repartitioning df2 to 4 yields a great performance improvement.

Comment: @Fulco `groupBy` will group your data first locally. Check getNumPartitions before and after the `groupBy().agg()`. Is it the same? Then, when you sort you will presort locally first and then transfer all the data into one place. If your data let's say partitioned by the field you sort and also presorted within a partition, then you don't have to transfer much, you have the right order already right?

Comment: @Fulco in case my answer solved your problem, could you please mark it as a best answer?

Comment: The evolution of the number of partitions is as follows; original=1, after `groupBy().agg()`=200, after `sortBy()`=4 or ±170. The `sortBy()` step is the part where the number of partitions differs, but I'm still clueless as to why this happens. I've since adjusted `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to be 4 on my local machine, as opposed to the default 200, which has improved Spark's performance overall on my machine. I need to figure out how to sensibly handle this setting when I move to a cluster.